# My custom annotation with @Repeatable dont work when I annotated twice

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I'm creating some annotations, and one of them I trying to enable to annotate twice. I use @Repeatable and created the conteiner. But when I use the annotation twice it appears that it needs to use @Repeatable.
As shown in the image below:

[image]

**Message error:** **Duplicate annotation of non-repeatable type @TX2Value. Only annotation types marked @Repeatable can be used multiple times at one target.**

```
@Repeatable(TX2ValueContainer.class) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE })
public @interface TX2Value {
    String name();
    ...
}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE })
@interface TX2ValueContainer {
    TX2Value[] value();
}

public void TestA() {
    @TX2Value(name="test01")
    @TX2Value(name="test02")
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles for me: https://ideone.com/BXMjNY. Double-check that the `TX2Value` class being used is actually the one you think it is?

Comment: [Do repeating annotations need a public container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30793047/2711488)